# Android JSONArray length value 0

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm trying to get my JSONArray length value which I used for my spinner but it always returns 0 even when the spinner has more value than 0. Here is my code

Class ConfigJSON

```
public class ConfigJSON {
      public static int value;
      public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

Main Activity

```
protected void onCreate{
    getData();
    new UpdateUser.GetUserInfo(UpdateUser.this).execute();
}

public void getData() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            JSONObject j = null;
            try {
                j = new JSONObject(response);
                result = j.getJSONArray(ConfigJSON.JSON_ARRAY);
                ConfigJSON.value = result.length();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private class GetUserInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    //Do Stuff before PostExecute

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        //The textview will output the JSONArray length
        TextView msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtmsg);
        msg.setText(Integer.toString(ConfigJSON.value));

        int index;
        for (int i=0;i<ConfigJSON.value;i++){
            if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equals("stuff")){
                index = i;
                spinner.setSelection(index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The whole point of this code is to get the JSONArray value so I can have a loop to setSelection in spinner but the value is always 0 so the spinner will always select the first value. I change the value in the loop like this to test if the setSelection is broken

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
         if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equals("stuff")){
           index = i;
             spinner.setSelection(index);
         }
}
```

The spinner works fine so I remove

```
new UpdateUser.GetUserInfo(UpdateUser.this).execute();
```

in onCreate and put it in getData

```
public void getData() {
    //Same as the getData above but only this line at the end
    new UpdateUser.GetUserInfo(UpdateUser.this).execute();
}
```

because I want to make sure the GetUserInfo will run after the value from getData is set. But it still returns 0 even when the getData have 3 values in it. So how do I get the result.length() value and use it in the GetUserInfo?

Comment: so what is `string` here?

Comment: it is some stuff so I can compare with the spinner value and select that spinner value if it is true. I will edit it so people won't ask this question agian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make sure the GetUserInfo will run after the value from
>   getData is set

Volley network calls are asynchronous so execute the task after the network call completion, as

```
public void getData() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            JSONObject j = null;
            try {
                j = new JSONObject(response);
                result = j.getJSONArray(ConfigJSON.JSON_ARRAY);
                ConfigJSON.value = result.length();
                new UpdateUser.GetUserInfo(UpdateUser.this).execute();
                //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding